# REST API test using Jersey Test Framework

Tags: rest, unit-testing, jersey, mockito, jersey-test-framework

My REST API defined in REST.class is as below,

```js
@GET
@Path("/somepath")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getSomething() {
    List<SomeObject> someList = new ArrayList<>();
    //.. based on some logic Adding SomeObject to the someList
    return Response.ok(someList).build();
}
```

I am trying to run Unit test for the above path by mocking the REST object as SomeObject wont be initialized for the test.

Below is the test code,

```js
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class RESTTest extends JerseyTest{

    
    @Mock
    private SomeObject someObj;
    
    @Mock
    private REST rest;
    private Response clientResponse;

    @Override
    protected Application configure(){
        ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(REST.class);
        return config;
    }


@Before
    public void setUp(){
        rest = mock(REST.class);
        SomeObject someObj = new SomeObject("String1","String2");
        List<SomeObject> someList = new ArrayList<>();
        someList.add(someObj);

        clientResponse = Response.ok(someList).build();

        when(rest.getSomething()).thenReturn(clientResponse);
    }

@Test
public void getSomethingTest() throws Exception {

    Response get = target("/somepath").request().get();
        
    assertThat(get.getStatus(), is(200));

}
}
```

Problem is I am facing NULLPointerException where I do get response from the target.

```js
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:566)
 at org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest.target(JerseyTest.java:580)
 at io.RESTTest.getSomething(RESTTest.java:72)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
 at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
 at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
 at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
 at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
 at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
 at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
 at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
 at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Can someone please suggest me a way to het the response from the REST API or tell me why there is a NULLPointerException

Comment: Post the complete test. It's unclear how the application uses your mock REST object.

Comment: I don't have any experience with Jersey, and I don't know if the exception is caused by this problem, but Jersey won't use the mock REST instance that you're creating. It doesn't even know it exists. It will create its own real instance of REST. You need to somehow give the mock instance of REST (instead og its class) to the ResourceConfig.